# Prevent duplicates in Elasticsearch object array upon insert

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I have the following document in my index:

```
{
  id: 1
  cities: [
    {id:1,name:"ny"},
    {id:2,name:"sf"}
  ]
}
```

How do I write an update script so that when I insert { id:1,name:"ny" } again it doesn't create a duplicate entry?

Currently I have the following groovy script but it keeps giving me error:

```
if (!ctx._source.cities) { 
  ctx._source.cities = [city]
} else { 
  ctx._source.cities= (ctx._source.cities+ [city]).unique{ a, b -> a.id == b.id }
}
```

I think the problem is that I am accessing object property incorrectly. Please advice. Thanks!

Comment: What error do you get? Please specify. Have you enabled scripting in `elasticsearch.yml`?

Comment: turns out it's i should use <=> operator instead of ==. Unique function expects the closure to return integer instead of boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error `groovy code`.

Use `unique` as mentioned below:

```
ctx._source.cities= (ctx._source.cities+ [city]).unique{it.id}
```

Hope this helps